Returning C++20 ranges from a method
I have a class, which stores an std::map<K, V> map_ as the private attribute.
Now I want to provide an API to list existing keys in it.
C++20 views seems good, because they have std::views::keys. I've tried to use it this way:
// .hpp file
class Data {
public:
    auto keys() const;
private:
    std::map<K, V> map_;
};

// .cpp file
auto Data::keys() const {
    return map_ | std::views::keys;
}

int main() {
    // ...
    auto k = data.keys(); // ERROR: a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined
}

Its a little bit confusing that the compiler cant deduce the type of k variable in such a simple case.
Then I realized, that it behaves like a template function and tried the following:
// .hpp file
class Data {
public:
    std::ranges::view auto keys() const;
private:
    std::map<K, V> map_;
};

std::ranges::view auto Data::keys() const noexcept {
    return std::views::keys(map_);
}

int main() {
    // ...
    auto k = data.keys(); // ERROR: multiple definitions of keys()
}

Finally I've fixed it via adding an inline:
// .hpp file
class Data {
public:
    inline std::ranges::view auto keys() const;
private:
    std::map<K, V> map_;
};

std::ranges::view auto Data::keys() const noexcept {
    return std::views::keys(map_);
}

And now it works. But it seems like a mess. I dont see the underlying type of the view in the function interface. Returning std::vector<K> shows us we get a collection of K's. std::ranges::view auto doesnt... (current implementation via C++17 copies the keys into an std::vector<K> on each call and I'm trying to avoid this allocation)
What am I missing here? Could the underlying type of the view be the part of the return type?
Note I'm using a C++20, latest MSVC compiler and CMake 3.28.1 to build this all (if it can help)

See How can I specify the return type of a function that returns the result of a ranges pipeline?

You can define your own concept view_for<T, ElemType> and use view_for<K> in place of std::ranges::views
